# What is the sum of the numbers in the shaded circles?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Each of the 6 circles contains a different counting number. The sum of all 6 numbers is 21.The sum of the 3 numbers along each side of the triangle is shown in the diagram. so What is the sum of the numbers in the shaded circles?

**Note that obviously the answer is easy. But what kind of ways you suggest for this problem?**

[image]

Comment: 'i think this question by simple face': can anybody decipher this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ the shaded corners. $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ the white ones.

$$X_1+Y_1+X_2=8$$
$$X_2+Y_2+X_3=8$$
$$X_1+Y_3+X_3=14$$
$$X_1+X_2+X_3+Y_1+Y_2+Y_3=21$$

Adding the three first equations:

$$2X_1+2X_2+2X_3+Y_1+Y_2+Y_3=30$$

And substract this equation with the fourth one:

$$X_1+X_2+X_3=9$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $$8+8+14=({\rm sum \space of \space white \space balls})+2({\rm sum \space of \space shaded \space balls}).$$ You can take it from here.

Comment: @bluebird7: this answer looks good to me.

Comment: see the latest answer !

Comment: @bluebird7: 'the latest answer': Do we have to work out which one that is, based on the time of you comment? I'd rather you just told us which answer you mean.

Comment: @bluebird7 It's not false but it's not an answer, really, more like a hint. He's telling you that summing the sides overcounts the shaded balls (doublecounts them, to be more specific).

Answer (score 1):

9.

The numbers in the triangle are:

5

2 6

1 4 3

Two of the sides sum to 8 and one side sums to 14, and the whole thing sums to 21 as specified.

Comment: From the question: "Each of the 6 circles contains a different counting number."

Comment: Yes, you're right, Marvin.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\text{ (Sum of shaded balls)}+\text{sum of unshaded balls}=8+8+14=30 \tag1$$
A/Q
$$\text{(sum of shaded balls)}+\text{sum of unshaded balls}=21 \tag2$$

Subtracting (1) & (2), Sum of shaded balls=9.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your answer could be formatted better. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).